# when using vimdiff how do I find the bottom of a block of changes

Tags: vim, vimdiff

When using vimdiff there are times that I want to select a change, not just the top line of the change. what I've been doing is manually positioning the cursor at the bottom of the change and then using a macro which does a

```
V[c{command such as y or d}
```

. I Would like to extend my macro to do something more along the lines of

```
/pattern/(in change)^M(find last line  in change)V[cd
```

.
Any advice or related information (i.e. diff specific addresses) you have would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Why do you want to select a change in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My [diffwindow_movement plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3719) provides `[C` and `]C` motions that go to the end of a change, and also an `ic` "inner change" text object to select / operate on it.